# Number of binary strings with $n$ ones and $m$ zeros

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, binary

$f(n,m)$ is the number of binary strings with up to $n$ ones and up to $m$ zeros.

Prove that the number of possible strings is: $${n+m+2 \choose n+1} -1$$

I got to the point that:
$$\sum_{a=0}^n \sum_{b=0}^m {a+b \choose a}$$

And I also understand that there are $(n+1)$ options for the amount of ones and $(m+1)$ options for the amount of zeros.

Comment: I fixed the question - it is up to n ones and up to m ones.

Comment: So your target is to find $$\sum_{k=0}^m \binom{r+k}{k}.$$ Use induction (unless you have a better idea).

Comment: What is r and k?

Comment: $r$ is an arbitrary non-negative integer, and $k$ is the index variable of the sum. There is a nice simple formula for that sum. Your inner sum is of that form, and then the outer sum becomes one of that form (almost, there is a _small_ difference).

Comment: Is r just an arbitrary integer? Still, what you have written makes no sence to me.

Comment: Would it make things clearer if in Daniel's comment you replaced $r$ with $a$?

Comment: I would be glad if there was an proper answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As remarked by Daniel Fischer above, you can apply the "hockey stick" identities to find your sum; these are the sums going down the diagonals of Pascal's triangle:

For the inner sum, use

$\binom{a}{a}+\binom{a+1}{a}+\binom{a+2}{a}+\cdots+\binom{a+m}{a}=\binom{a+m+1}{a+1}$;

and for the outer sum, use

$\binom{m+1}{0}+\binom{m+1}{1}+\binom{m+2}{2}+\cdots+\binom{m+n+1}{n+1}=\binom{m+n+2}{n+1}$.

(The first sum goes down a right-to-left diagonal, and
the second sum goes down a left-to-right diagonal.)

Answer (score 6):

Let $S$ be the set of binary strings of length $n+m+2$ with $n+1$ ones and $m+1$ zeroes.  By definition, $$|S|=\binom{n+m+2}{n+1}.$$

Let $L \in S$.  Let $\beta$ be the bit in the last place of $L$ and $\overline{\beta}$ be the complement of $\beta$.

Since $n \geq 0$ and $m \geq 0$, we know $L$ has the form $$L=(\text{substring } X,\overbrace{\overline{\beta},\overline{\beta},\ldots,\overline{\beta}}^i,\overbrace{\beta,\beta,\ldots,\beta}^j)$$ where $i \geq 1$ (and $i$ is the maximum such positive integer possible) and $j \geq 1$.  We observe:

- The substring $X$ obtained is a binary string with at most $n$ ones and at most $m$ zeroes.
- Every non-empty binary string $X$ with at most $n$ ones and at most $m$ zeroes can be obtained uniquely in this way (by appending ones and zeroes to it in the appropriate way).
- The empty binary string $X$ can be obtained in exactly two ways.

Hence there are $|S|-1$ binary strings with at most $n$ ones and at most $m$ zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

We can find the sum by generating functions
\begin{align*}
  \sum_{b=0}^{m} \binom{a+b}{b} &= [x^m] \frac{1}{(1-x)}\frac{1}{(1-x)^{a+1}} \\
  \implies \sum_{a=0}^{n} \sum_{b=0}^{m} \binom{a+b}{b} &= [x^m]\sum_{a=0}^{n}\frac{1}{(1-x)^{a+2}} \\
  &= [x^m]\left(\frac{1}{x\left(1-x\right)^{n+2}}-\frac{1}{x\left(1-x\right)}\right) \\
    &= \binom{m+n+2}{m+1}-1
\end{align*}