# Help with Combinatorical formula

Tags: combinatorics

I tried to prove the next formula.. this is the case:

$f(n,m)$ represents the number of binary strings (including the empty string) which have no more 
than $n$ 1's and $m$ 0's. I need to show that:

$$f(n,m)={n+m+2 \choose n+1}-1$$
Could you help me?
Thanks!

Comment: I have posted a solution using generating function in the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't thought too hard about a clever solution but if $g(x,y)$ represents the number of strings with $x$ 1's and $y$ 0's, then your looking for $$\sum_{x=0}^{n}\sum_{y=0}^{m} g(x,y).$$ Perhaps you could look start by looking at $\sum_{y=0}^{m} g(a,y)$ for fixed $a$?

If this doesn't prove useful there may be a clever bijection you could use somewhere.

Comment: The nice bijection i was talking about can be found here, turns out this question has been asked before http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473760/number-of-binary-strings-with-n-ones-and-m-zeros